# Stata overlapping variables labels

Tags: stata

I downloaded a package on the net:

```
net install cleanplots, from("https://tdmize.github.io/data/cleanplots")
set scheme cleanplots, perm
graph set window fontface "Arial Narrow"
```

and it has ruined Stata default visualisation:

`graph hbar (count), over(School)`

[image: Broken Stata defaults]

My y labels overlap

My x labels are not under the tick marks

My chosen font isn't working

My font size isn't working.

**How do I reset all defaults (especially visualisation setting eg "schemeplot set") and delete all packages?**

I deleted Stata, reinstalled it, and it is so wise it kept all my defaults.

Comment: This started unclearly "I downloaded a package on from the net" and didn't get clearer. What did you download?

Comment: Apologies @NickCox—hopefully it is more readable now.

Comment: `set scheme s1color, perm` should have been enough to reverse that (or any other scheme). However, it's hard to believe that something else was not going on to produce such a mess.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "it has ruined Stata default visualization", what you mean is that the new scheme you are using is not compatible with your labels, likely because the scheme you set activated certain parameters, like the label width, etc. Since the scheme is changed, it is not the default scheme anymore. You could reset the default color-scheme by typing:

`set_defaults graphics`

Then, you could change the other settings, such as the background color and grid lines using the default scheme if it does solve the font problem.

If you want to stick to the new scheme, what I would do is explore the axis label options, in particular label size, angle and wrapping. You could just specify schemes for one graph at a time if it doesn't work for all graphs by typing:

`... , scheme(lean1)`

in the graph options.